# How to shrink IRISTEMP db in runtime?

Tags: intersystems-iris

After running an extensive block of daily statistics my IRISTEMP
has expanded dramatically. But FreeSpace shows 97% unused and FREE space.
How can I shrink IRISTEMP in runtime **without** shutdown and manual intervention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean 'without manual intervention' ?
You can shrink it with the database tools (Do ^DATABASE, option 13 (compact free space in a database) & option 12 (return free space for a database). But that is a 'manual' intervention.
It will only happen automatically when you restart Iris.

Comment: Dear Dany !
on Win IIRS.DAT in %installdir%\mgr\iristemp\ grows and grows 
and never gets smaller.  It is just the same as it was in Caché for ages.  
no automatic!  
Only delete during a shutdown reduces it's size:
Option 12 does it.